# SDL.h not found on g++ compile

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, g++, sdl

<strike>Using OSX and vim...
Downloaded SDL2 from the website, then moved the SDL2.framework into /Library/Frameworks/</strike>

Using tutorial code, and Makefile... SDL.h is not found.

Makefile: `g++`sdl-config --cflags --libs`sdltest.cpp -o sdltest`

I've read numerous things about pointing the compiler to the framework, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work, and  I thought /Library/Frameworks/ was the default area for the compiler to look

Got it to work.

Getting this to work took multiple tries, but the root of the issue for each try was that most of the Tutorials I was looking at were for SDL1.2 when I was using SDL2.

This changed flags in the make file, directories to search in and other things. Interestingly, I could never get the compiler to see SDL.h when it was in the /Library/Frameworks/ directory. However using Macports to install SDL2 allowed me to point the compiler to where Macports installed SDL2 header files - /opt/local/include/SDL2

That seems to have done it for me

Comment: It is not clear what you are showing under the "Makefile:" heading.

Comment: There's not much more to the Makefile, it's only 5 lines

`sdltest: sdltest.cpp`
`g++sdl-config --cflags --libssdltest.cpp -o sdltest`
`clean: ` 
`rm sdltest`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, because I was having similar difficulties!  There seems to be a dearth of detailed and helpful tutorials on how to install SDL2 using Macports.

I got it working!  Here are the steps:

1. Visit this link to find the Macports package appropriate for your version of Mac OS X. Install the version you need, and once that is done, proceed to step 2.

   https://www.macports.org/install.php
2. After installation is done, visit this link to find the SDL2 port.

   https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=libsdl

   The one I needed was the third from the top, called `libsdl2`.  I will be providing the name for you so feel free to visit the link simply for your own edification.
3. Open the Terminal, and type `sudo port install libsdl2`.  If all goes to plan, you should see it installing and updating.  Once it is complete, you should have a functional installation of the SDL2 Header files, (ending in `.h`), Static Library files (ending in `.a`) and Dynamic Library files (which contain `dylib`).  You may have to do some poking around in Finder to locate where it installed.
4. The advantage of this workaround is the ability to use SDL with other IDE's besides Xcode, Eclipse for instance.  Whereas Xcode requires you to assign a path of `/Library/Frameworks`, this technique should allow you to use the IDE of your choosing.
5. The final step is going into your IDE and assigning the build paths to these newly installed and compiled SDL files.  For instance, the paths for mine are `/opt/local/include` and `/opt/local/lib`.  Be mindful of the fact that your path may differ from these, but these examples should give you an idea of where to look.

Hopefully this is helpful for somebody!

Comment: I know as a new user you cannot comment, but it would be appropriate to gain some reputation in order to take part in this question as you have not posted an answer that provides any details to other users.

Comment: Users in the review queue, be aware that this answer has been updated to provide an answer to the question now.